# MacOSX: OSAtomic vs OSAtomicBarrier

Tags: macos

For the functions here:

```
#include <libkern/OSAtomic.h>
```

there are OSAtomic and OSAtomicBarrier versions.

However, the documentation does not show sample code for:

1. When is it safe to use just `OSAtomic`, without the `OSAtomicBarrier` version
2. When is it that `OSAtomic` would be *unsafe*, but `OSAtomicBarrier` would be safe.

Can anyone provide explainations + sample codes?

[Random ramblings of "your opinion" without actual code is useless. Readers: please down vote such answers; and vigrously upvote answers with actual code.]

[C/C++ code preferred; Assembly okay too.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Intel and uniprocessor platforms, it doesn't matter.

For multiprocessor PPC systems, you should always use the barrier variety of functions, unless the atomic store affects no data *other* than the atomic variable.

The following would not be ok:

```
data_structure[y].data++;
OSAtomicIncrement32(y);
```

You *must* use a barrier here, because other threads may see data_structure as out of date.

However, if you are using an atomic variable for some purpose where it stands alone, you may omit  the barrier:

```
// y is not used to access any other data
OSAtomicIncrement32(y);
```

Fine, as long as the value of y does not affect the variable of any shared data structure.

Essentially, it's a cache flush.  You can always safely use the barrier functions, but in some cases, you may be able to improve performance by not using the barrier functions, such as if y is not used relative to a data structure.  There are probably not many cases where you can use the functions without the barrier.

Comment: Why does it not matter on Intel multiprocessor systems?

Comment: This explains it at a high level better than I can:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8211

Comment: The following would not be ok:
data_structure[y].data++;
OSAtomicIncrement32(y);


Next code is not ok also:

data_structure[y].data++;
OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier(y);

Comment: @Speakus And then, what is OK version?

Answer (score 4):

I think this article a more detailed explain of what's going here: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-03-04-a-tour-of-osatomic.html. Pretty good read.